# Oracle Analytical Desktop Variable Prompt issue

Tags: oracle-bi, oracle-analytics

[Before Saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kevOL.png)

[After Saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrSkq.png)

In Oracle Analytical Desktop, I am using Variable Prompt (Custom Visualization), After saving my canvas the dropdown values of Variable Prompt Disappear .Only the selected value left in the dropdown.

OAD can't retain values like Tableau.

Need Guidance how to retain values using Variable Prompts.